# What is distinction between initialize method vs prototype in setClass to set default values in R S4?

Tags: r, r-s4

In R S4 OOP, I'm aware of 2 ways so set default values for a particular class.

1.) Using prototype in `setClass()`

```r
setClass("Person",
         slots = c(
           name = "character",
           age = "numeric"
         ), 
         prototype = list(
           name = "Jim",
           age = 25
         )
         )
```

2.) Using initialize in `setMethod()`

```r
setMethod("initialize", "Person",
          function(.Object,
                   name,
                   age,
                   ...) {
              .Object@name <- "Jim"
              .Object@age <- 25
            validObject(.Object)
            return(.Object)
          }
)

assign("Person", Person, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Can anyone please elaborate on the distinction between these two i.e. why would we want to include a separate initialize method vs using `prototype()` in `setClass()`? What is S4 best practice?

Thank you in advance for the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prototype is only able to handle simple cases; in particular the value of slots cannot depend on each other and the user cannot specify any dynamic values. For example, if you have a simple class

```
setClass("personInfo",
  slots=list(
    age="numeric",
    ageSquared="numeric"
  ), prototype=prototype(
    age=18,
    ageSquared=18^2
) -> personInfo
```

then the prototype can only create 18-year old people. Instead, it is more useful to create an initialize method as a function of `age`, which can then set both `age` and `ageSquared` to the relevant values.

Also note that if you assign the results of `setClass` into an object (as I did in the example above, assigning it into an object called `personInfo` then `personInfo` *becomes* a call to `initialize` and you can now call e.g.

```
personInfo(age=10,ageSquared=100)
```

(though this isn't ideal in this case as you have to explicitly supply `ageSquared` when you could have had the method do that for you.)

I would recommend:

- using a prototype for any slot that has a reasonable default value (every class/slot has an implicit prototype anyway)
- always keeping the return value from `setClass` as an object
- over-riding that with a method of `initialize` if some slots depend on others (like `ageSquared` here)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, very helpful.  Is the assign() function necessary in my second example, or, is this better done by creating a wrapper function i.e. `Person <- function(...) {
  initialize(new("Person"), ...)
}`

Comment: you don't need it in your case because your constructor is a simple one (you specify the contents of each slot independently). You could have done `setClass("Person",...) -> Person` and the result would be the same. In more complicated cases (such as the `personInfo` in my example, if you want the constructor to be able to work when given only one argument (and taking the square or square root to get the other one) you need an explicit `initialize` method.

Comment: In fact your second example is completely broken. The returned objects will always have age 25 and name Jim, regardless of what arguments the user specifies. I'm surprised the last line of it works at all!